# Error flask server

Tags: python, flask, qr

Holaaaa, ando haciendo una aplicacion que lea un codigo qr y me envie los datos del mismo qr como mensaje por telegram, segun lei debia hacerlo con una pagina externa para que el servidor flask detectara cuando alguien entrara a esa pagina y me enviara los datos, sin embargo me manda este error:
Error al monitorear: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

Este es mi codigo:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests, json, time, threading

app = Flask(__name__)
url_a_monitorear = "https://projecti8.my.canva.site"
@app.route('/Proyecto', methods=['POST'])
def monitorear():
    try:
        response = requests.get(url_a_monitorear)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            usuario_data = request.form
            datos_usuario = f"Nombre: {usuario_data.get('nombre')}, Cuenta: {usuario_data.get('cuenta')}"
            url = "https://api.telegram.org/botomitidoporseguridad/sendMessage"
            payload = json.dumps({
                "text": f"El usuario que ingreso fue: {datos_usuario}",
                "chat_id": "omitidoporseguridad"
            })
            headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
            print(response.text)
            print("Acceso detectado en la página. Enviar mensaje a Telegram.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al monitorear: {str(e)}")
def monitoreo_periodico():
    while True:
        monitorear()
        time.sleep(60) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=monitoreo_periodico)
    monitor_thread.start()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: [¿Investigaste lo suficiente?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34123159)